# https in url with out showing port number 8443

Tags: java, xml

how can we hide the port number of https? Is there any changes on server.xml
i have the following code below in my server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:/Documents and Settings/tony/new_test.keystore" keypass="changeit" />

<Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" port="80" redirectPort="8443" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" >
</Connector>

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" protocolHandlerClassName="org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler" redirectPort="8443">
</Connector>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way the port will be hidden in most browsers is if it is the standard port for https, 443.  You could set up your server to forward 443 to 8443.